# my keyPressed function isn't being called

Tags: java, actionlistener

I'm working on a school assignment in which I need to make a JComponent that makes some objects (defined in my Player Class) move around. In order to do this I need to use the keyPressed function of the KeyListener Interface but I can't get my program to call it. This I know because the println at the beginning of keyPressed doesn't print when I press keys.

Following is the relevant code.
BackgroundMain.java

```
package edu.hiram.cs.cpsc172;

import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
/**
 * 
 * @author tricksimon
 * Class that creates the JFrame, and gives instructions for the frame.
 */
public class BackgroundMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        // Learned in Stackoverflow
        frame.setTitle("Game Background");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        BackgroundComponent background = new BackgroundComponent();
        frame.add(background);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

BackgroundComponent.java

```
package edu.hiram.cs.cpsc172;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

/**
 * 
 * @author Simonpj
 * Class that makes the many parts of the background.
 */

public class BackgroundComponent extends JComponent implements KeyListener {

    private long lastTime;

    private int upArrow;
    private int downArrow;
    private int enterKey;
    private int leftArrow;
    private int rightArrow;
    private int spaceKey;
    private Player player;

    public BackgroundComponent(){
        player = new Player(200, 200, Color.BLUE);
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        upArrow=38;
        downArrow = 40;
        enterKey = 10;
        leftArrow = 37;
        rightArrow = 39;
        spaceKey = 32;

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setBackground(Color.yellow);

        //Grass for the scene
        Rectangle box = new Rectangle(0, 528, 2000, 1000);
        g2.draw(box);
        Color green = new Color(0, 255, 0);
        g2.setColor(Color.green);
        g2.fill(box);

        //Rectangle representing the sky
        Rectangle box1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 2000, 530);
        Color cyan = new Color(0, 255, 255);
        g2.setColor(Color.cyan);
        g2.draw(box1);
        g2.fill(box1);

        //Rectangle representing the house
        Rectangle box2 = new Rectangle(0, 530, 600, 500);
        g2.draw(box2);
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.fill(box2);

        //Rectangle representing the door of the house
        Rectangle box3 = new Rectangle(265, 650, 80, 150);
        g2.draw(box3);
        Color brown = new Color(139, 69, 19);
        g2.setColor(brown);
        g2.fill(box3);

        //Ellipse representing the door knob 
        Ellipse2D.Double ellipse1 = new Ellipse2D.Double(330, 710, 10, 10);
        g2.draw(ellipse1);
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.fill(ellipse1);

        //Ellipse representing the sun
        Ellipse2D.Double ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(1320, -20, 150, 150);
        g2.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g2.draw(ellipse);
        g2.fill(ellipse);

        //Create a polygon for the roof of the house
        int[] xCoords = new int[]{0, 300, 600};
        int[] yCoords = new int[]{530, 5, 530};
        Polygon poly = new Polygon(xCoords, yCoords, 3);
        g2.setColor(brown);
        g2.fillPolygon(poly);

        //Windows
        Rectangle box4 = new Rectangle(100, 600, 70, 70);
        g2.draw(box4);
        g2.setColor(Color.blue);
        g2.fill(box4);

        Rectangle box5 = new Rectangle(126, 600, 15, 71);
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.draw(box5);
        g2.fill(box5);

        Rectangle box6 = new Rectangle(100, 628, 70, 15);
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.draw(box6);
        g2.fill(box6);

        Rectangle box7 = new Rectangle(450, 600, 70, 70);
        g2.draw(box7);
        g2.setColor(Color.blue);
        g2.fill(box7);

        Rectangle box8 = new Rectangle(476, 600, 15, 71);
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.draw(box8);
        g2.fill(box8);

        Rectangle box9 = new Rectangle(450, 628, 70, 15);
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.draw(box9);
        g2.fill(box9);

        // Drawing a car
        //Main Car
        Rectangle box10 = new Rectangle(750, 655, 300, 100);
        g2.setColor(Color.blue);
        g2.draw(box10);
        g2.fill(box10);

        Rectangle box11 = new Rectangle(830, 620, 150, 50);
        g2.draw(box11);
        g2.fill(box11);



        //Wheels
        Ellipse2D.Double ellipse2 = new Ellipse2D.Double(795, 725, 50, 50);
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.draw(ellipse2);
        g2.fill(ellipse2);

        Ellipse2D.Double ellipse3 = new Ellipse2D.Double(950, 725, 50, 50);
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.draw(ellipse3);
        g2.fill(ellipse3);

        Ellipse2D.Double ellipse4 = new Ellipse2D.Double(963, 738, 25, 25);
        g2.setColor(Color.white);
        g2.draw(ellipse4);
        g2.fill(ellipse4);

        Ellipse2D.Double ellipse5 = new Ellipse2D.Double(807.5, 738, 25, 25);
        g2.setColor(Color.white);
        g2.draw(ellipse5);
        g2.fill(ellipse5);


        //Text for the background
        Font courierBold20 = new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 20);
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.setFont(courierBold20);
        g2.drawString("My Game Background", 650, 270);

        UFO u = new UFO(320,240, Color.BLUE);
        u.draw(g2);

        UFO u1 = new UFO(60,30, Color.RED);
        u1.draw(g2);

        UFO u2 = new UFO(900,180, Color.magenta);
        u2.draw(g2);

        Player p = new Player(700, 644, Color.DARK_GRAY);
        p.draw(g2);

        Player p1 = new Player(390, 644, Color.DARK_GRAY);
        p1.draw(g2);

        player.draw(g2);


    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("check");
        if (e.getKeyCode() == upArrow){
            player.increaseSize();
        }

        if (e.getKeyCode() == downArrow){
            player.decreaseSize();
        }

        if (e.getKeyCode() == enterKey){
            player.resetSize();
        }

        if (e.getKeyCode() == leftArrow){
            player.moveLeft();
        }

        if (e.getKeyCode() == rightArrow){
            player.moveRight();
        }

        if (e.getKeyCode() == spaceKey){
            player.newColor();
        }
        player.move(e.getKeyCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Player.java

```
package edu.hiram.cs.cpsc172;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * 
 * @author Simonpj
 * Class that creates a player.
 */
public class Player {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private Color userColor;
    private double size;
    private Random rand;

    /**
     * Constructor for the Player class
     * @param x X Coordinate for Player
     * @param y Y Coordinate for Player
     * @param userColor Color of the Player
     */
    public Player(int x, int y, Color userColor) {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.userColor=userColor;
        this.size=1.0;
        this.rand = new Random();
    }

    /**
     * Draws the Player
     * @param g Graphics object
     */
    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.scale(size, size);
        //Body
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 45, 75);
        g2.setColor(userColor);
        g2.fill(rect);
        g2.draw(rect);

        //Head
        Ellipse2D.Double ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(x + 4, y - 35, 35, 35);
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.fill(ellipse);

        //Leg
        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(x + 12, y + 76, 20, 45);
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.fill(rect1);
        g2.draw(rect1);

        //Arms
        Rectangle rect3 = new Rectangle(x + 16, y + 15, 13, 45);
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.fill(rect3);
        g2.draw(rect3);

        //reset scale
        g2.scale(1.0/size, 1.0/size);
    }


    public void changeColor(Color color) {
        userColor=color;
    }

    public void move(int keyPressed) {
        System.out.println(keyPressed); //comment out this line once you know the ints for the keys you need
    }

    public void increaseSize() {
        size*=1.1;

    }

    public void decreaseSize() {
        size*=0.9;

    }

    public void resetSize() {
        size = 1.0;

    }

    public void moveLeft() {
        //poly.translate(-2,0);
        this.x -= 2;
    }

    public void moveRight() {
        //poly.translate(2,0);
        this.x += 2;
    }

    public void newColor() {

        float r = rand.nextFloat();
        float g = rand.nextFloat();
        float b = rand.nextFloat();

        Color randomColor = new Color(r, g, b);

        userColor = randomColor;



    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see that you're ever calling `addKeyListener` inside `BackgroundComponent`.  You need to do that in order for the `keyPressed` method to get called.

Answer (score 0):

You must add your object as a keyListener, likely in the constructor:

```
addKeyListener(this);
```